# Проблема с сохранением данных в последнем из заполняемых полей

Tags: delphi, firebird

У меня есть *TIBDataSet*, *TDataSource*, и *TDBGrid* вкотором отоображается 2 поля все связано и работает.
При добавлении записи (через *TDBGrid*) и фиксации, данные сохраняются только в одном поле *FIELD1*, а в *FIELD2* данные не сохраняются. Но зато при редактировании *FIELD2*, данные сохраняются.
Проверил запрос «*insert*» в *DataSet*, ошибки вроде нет.

Добавил компонент *TDBEdit*, подключил к *FIELD2*, при добавлении записи через *TDBEdit*, все прекрасно запоминается. Получается это где-то ошибка в поле *TDBGrid*?

P.S.
- вывел в *TDBGrid* все поля (всего их 7), при добавлении записи (через *TDBGrid*) и фиксации, уже заполнилось то поле которое не заполнялось, но не заполнилось последнее поле.
- Добавил на форму новые TIBDataSet, TDataSource, и TDBGrid, проделал туже операцию по добавлению записи, ситуация такая же...

Comment: в autoedit режиме что ли?

Comment: да, autoedit = true

Comment: "и фиксации" - это что?

Comment: "фиксация" - это нажатие на кнопку "V" DBNavigator (IBTransaction.CommitRetaining;)

Comment: Добавил на форму новые *TIBDataSet*, *TDataSource*, и *TDBGrid*, проделал туже операцию по добавлению записи, ситуация такая же...

Comment: **Ситуация решается, но КОРЯВО** - все поля/значения сохраняются в БД (при заполнении через DBGrid), в случае, когда после их заполнения, пердаешь фокус мыши на другой компонент (например Edit), а потом только делаешь "Post". И почему так не пойму

Comment: а зачем вообще в режиме авторедактирования делать `post`? enter нажал,  или фокус на следующую строку перевел и все вроде,  не?

Comment: хотя у вас тут в одном месте про пост, в другом про транзакцию

Comment: *@  teran* как раз да, если в *AutoEdit=true*, и после заполнения данными строки, не нажимать *DBNavigator*, а просто переходить на другую строку в *DBGrid*, то все значения запоминается. Но пользователь же после заполнения строки, нажимает галку на  *DBNavigator*. Поэтому я в "*BeforeAction*"  *DBNavigator*, передаю фокус какому-то другому компоненту и все работает, конечно это не очень красиво, но...